# Задать url на серверной стороне в ViewResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

В Home контроллере есть два метода:

```
public ViewResult FirstView ()
{
    return View();
}
//...
public ViewResult SecondView()
{

    if(условие){
       return View("FirstView");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Предполагается, что если при попытке обращения к представлению SecondView выполняется определённое условие (проверка), то происходит переход к представлению FirstSecond. Код работает, НО в адресной строке браузера после выполнения if мы видим localhost/Home/SecondView. Возможно ли сделать, чтобы при выполнении if менялась и адресная строка на localhost/Home/FirstView ?

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу следующим образом:

1. Поменял тип возвращаемого значения с ViewResult на ActionResult
2. заменил `return View("FirstView");` на `return  RedirectToAction("Authorization");`